How to find a module in deno?
I'm trying to follow the documentation on the page:
https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/get-started-sqlite
In the documentation it has this code snippet:
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/libsql';

However, I'm using Deno and I'm trying to use the recommended way of importing modules which is either via URL or import_map.json, the issue is that I can't seem to find where to actually import that {drizzle} from since on the page https://deno.land/x/drizzle@v0.23.85/mod.ts there only exists a drizzle function inside the postgres package which I don't think I'm supposed to use since I am using Turso.
How am I supposed to find the url for the 'drizzle-orm/libsql' or am I missing something here?
I have also tried using esm.sh to import it and the IDE gives me 3 options to import from, they all are using the postgres version, so it seems that this not yet available for deno?

The link that you provided doesn't mention Deno and it includes a code sample showing how to install the package from npm. The Deno docs include a section describing npm interop. Does that fully address your question? If so, I can write an answer based on it (or find a suitable duplicate target question). If not, what am I missing?

Does this answer your question? How to use npm module in DENO?

For anyone else stumbling upon this. You can actually import npm packages if you use the 'npm' prefix. This should work for all packages.
Example:
import { drizzle } from 'npm:drizzle-orm/postgres-js';


it's not works.... here is full details
